# Remote access SSH with PIVPN on RI3

Tags: vpn

I have a raspberry3 to my workplace and it is connected to internet by the LAN network.

I want to access to the pi-hole interface remotely from my home and by ssh for any configuration on it.

I installed PIVPN, with TCP port 443 because many ports are blocked at my work. I also create a certificate and put it on my PC. When I'm at home, i tested but it doesn't work and i think the main causes it's because during the connection it arrive to the IP public address of my work on 443 port and stop. How i can redirect them on my raspberry? I have not access to the firewall of my enterprise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way to access devices behind a firewall from outside is to configure port forwarding on the enterprise router/firewall. So you have to ask your security manager if he would like to give you access to your RasPi behind the firewall. There are of course ways to peek holes into the firewall but I don't believe that your security manager does like it.